# How to split data output of a custom post type loop

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop, split, wordpress-theming

How do I split the values within a custom post type loop so that the title is in the first loop which outputs in the first DIV and the content is in the second loop outputting in the second DIV? Two loops may not be the best way to do, I don't know. Somebody mentioned to me about one loop then storing in a string and then splitting the string. I have no idea how to do this either.

I also need a new row to begin once the number of posts reach 5.

Here's my PHP loop...

```
<?php
  $custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_args );
  query_posts(array( 'post_type' => array('team')) ); 

  if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : 
  /* Start my loop */
    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post();
      echo "<div>". the_title(); . "</div>";
      echo "<div>". the_content(); . "</div>";
    endwhile;
  endif;
?>
```

The HTML output i'm looking for as follows...

```
<div class"row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title chris"></div>
    <div class="title darren"></div>
    <div class="title ryan"></div>
    <div class="title john"></div>
    <div class="title emma"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title chris"></div>
    <div class="title darren"></div>
    <div class="title ryan"></div>
    <div class="title john"></div>
    <div class="title emma"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class"row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title chris"></div>
    <div class="title darren"></div>
    <div class="title ryan"></div>
    <div class="title john"></div>
    <div class="title emma"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title chris"></div>
    <div class="title darren"></div>
    <div class="title ryan"></div>
    <div class="title john"></div>
    <div class="title emma"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class"row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title chris"></div>
    <div class="title darren"></div>
    <div class="title ryan"></div>
    <div class="title john"></div>
    <div class="title emma"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title chris"></div>
    <div class="title darren"></div>
    <div class="title ryan"></div>
    <div class="title john"></div>
    <div class="title emma"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Pseudo Code...**

```
$team; // array
$avatar = '';
$memberinfo = '';
foreach ($team as $member){
    $avatar .= '<div>'. $member->avatar .'</div>';
    $memberinfo .= '<div class="content">'. $member->memberinfo .'</div>';

    if($newRow){
        echo $avatar;
        echo $memberinfo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you plz try this code.

```
<?php
/* To get current page from query var */
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('post_type' => array('post'),'posts_per_page' => -1,'paged' => $paged);

 /* Create custom WP_Query */
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$post_ids = array();
if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
    /* the wordpress loop */
    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post();
        /* Start my loop to get all post id in one array called "$post_ids" */
        $post_ids[] = get_the_id();
    endwhile;
    /* end of the loop */
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();


$count = 1;
$post_title = $post_content = '';
foreach( $post_ids as $post_id ) 
{
    if ($count%5 == 1)
    {  
         echo '<div class="row">';
    }
    $post_title .= '<div class="title">'.get_the_title($post_id).'</div>';
    $post_content .= '<div class="content">'.get_post_field('post_content', $post_id).'</div>';
    if ($count%5 == 0)
    {
        echo $post_title;
        echo  $post_content;
        echo "</div>";
        $post_title = $post_content = '';
    }
    $count++;
}
if ($count%5 != 1) {
    echo $post_title;
    echo  $post_content;
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

it will give out put see below.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="title">title1</div>
    <div class="title">title2</div>
    <div class="title">title3</div>
    <div class="title">title4</div>
    <div class="title">title5</div>
    <div class="content">content1</div>
    <div class="content">content2</div>
    <div class="content">content3</div>
    <div class="content">content4</div>
    <div class="content">content5</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="title">title6</div>
    <div class="title">title7</div>
    <div class="title">title8</div>
    <div class="title">title9</div>
    <div class="title">title10</div>
    <div class="content">content6</div>
    <div class="content">content7</div>
    <div class="content">content8</div>
    <div class="content">content9</div>
    <div class="content">content10</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="title">title11</div>
    <div class="title">title12</div>
    <div class="title">title13</div>
    <div class="title">title14</div>
    <div class="title">title15</div>
    <div class="content">content11</div>
    <div class="content">content12</div>
    <div class="content">content13</div>
    <div class="content">content14</div>
    <div class="content">content15</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It might work, but it really is very expensive, you are really hitting the db hard. On 20 posts you are doing more that 40 queries

Comment: For each post you are doing two queries, one to get the post title, one to get the content, everything of which was already in the first query. You need to go back and rework this from your first query to optimize it. You need one query, and one query only, not 40 plus queries :-)

Comment: That worked... genius :)

I have been given some Pseudo code which might stop the over querying of the DB.... i'll post above.

Comment: I've just realised i missed out a container DIVs for the titles and one for the content in each row, sorry :(

Comment: i've amended the HTML above to cate for container DIVs around each set of list items in each group.

Comment: @PieterGoosen you have any other solution for this? if you have any answer then post here.